# Countdown in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I need to give the countdown as shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100317090253/http://www.bidrivals.com/us/), for each item using ASP.NET with C#.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a webservice that can give the state (time left, current price, #bids etc) of all the items visible on the page back to the client.

The client uses typically AJAX / JSON to retrieve the state of all the items on the page and then jquery to update the countdown timers/bids on each item on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[setInterval](http://www.bidrivals.com/us/)** method to implement a count down timer.

You can get the initial time from the server. And then use javascript to get the count down timer working.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you could use ajax.
http://www.asp.net/ajax/

Specifically you could use this control
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AlwaysVisibleControl/AlwaysVisibleControl.aspx

Comment: I need to synchronize the time of all client in timely fashion. In the site mentioned the time coming from sever.

Answer (score 0):

That site is using AJAX, as you can see from the regular refreshes that occur to the individual timers. You can create a web service or web method to consume. If the times don't need to be refreshed during the life of the page, then I would stick with a simple JavaScript countdown using jQuery or the link the @kieran shared.