# Synchronize count down time for all users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to synchronize the count down time for all users. So it will display identical remaining time to all in asp.net.

Comment: Seems awfully identical to your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445337/count-down-in-asp-net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count down in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445337/count-down-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

What is the count down time?

In general to show the same information to all users you'd use something in an Application level variable which works the same way as `ViewState("")` or `Session("")` but is common to all users of an application.

e.g.

```
Application("CountdownRemaining") = Now.AddHours(1)
```

All users now have access to the same information in `Application("CountdownRemaining")`.

As you've tagged ASP.NET I assume you want some information on a web page, so why not have something in a Master Page which queries an Application variable?

Comment: I agree... if the need includes to view the same data in each user page, you can include some javascript timer or ajax query or something like that, that queries over your application variable

Comment: I have a products which have auction time as http://www.bidrivals.com/uk/

for this I need count down auction time.